# possible combination of images in Python

Tags: python

I am using Python "itertools.combinations" to to make the possible combinations of the images that I have and do the respective comparison between them. However, with this function for example given 4 images (A,B,C,D), I get AB AC AD BC BD CD combinations.

I want to replace Python "itertools.combinations" by a function that will give me only all the possible combination of one image with the rest, hence if A is the selected image, I want ONLY AB,AC,AD. Do you know how I can have that?

Comment: What do you mean by you want to replace `itertools.combinations`? Do you just want to write a new function or do you also want any code calling `itertools.combinations` to actually call your function?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want something like this:

```
def my_combinations(first, *others):
    for other in others:
        yield first + other
```

Example:

```
combs = my_combinations('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
print combs
print list(combs)
```

Output:

```
<generator object my_combinations at 0x105926230>
['AB', 'AC', 'AD']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split one of your images from others and combine them how you want. In this case using just list comprehension:

```
images = ('A','B','C','D')

first = images[0]  # just A
others = images[1:]  # just B,C,D

print([(first, img) for img in others])
# [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D')]
```